# NullPointerException on getting ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

I got entity Account with ManyToMany to entity Role.

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="Account_Role")
    private Set<Role> roles;

    // getters, setters
}
```

When i try to access relationship collection i got NullPointerException as roles is null:

```
Account account = new Account();
account.getRoles().size();
```

Shouldn't an empty set be injected into `roles`? Or is it default behaviour and I should control `roles` creation by:

```
   private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet()<>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just created an object

```
Account account = new Account();
```

that wasn't managed by JPA. How do you expect it to not be null?

Reference type instance variables are, by default, assigned `null`. `Set` is a reference type. You should create the `Set` yourself (as you've suggested).

```
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet()<>;
```

Or retrieve an entity instance from a JPA `EntityManager` instance

```
Account account = entityManager.find(Account.class, 42);
```